# Flutter - How to enable TextFormField using Switch button

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I disabled the TextFormField and I want to enable it again using the Custom Switch. Package is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch)
and this is the code

```
bool isEnabled = false;

CustomSwitch(
   activeColor: Colors.greenAccent,
   value: isEnabled,
   onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
         isEnabled = value;
      });
   },
),


TextFormField(
   enabled: isEnabled,
   decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
   
),
```

Do you have any idea how can I enable/disable the textformfield by using switch button?
and it's okay if I use checkbox instead of switch. TIA!

Comment: Does the above code snippet not work?

Comment: Yup the switch is working, it can enable and disable but the textformfield can't enable/disable when the switch is on/off. It stays disable/false

Comment: Are both of these widgets getting displayed on the same screen? If yes then the `enabled` param should work as expected.

Comment: Not in front of AS but shouldn't the set state call be isEnabled != isEnabled to switch from true to false and back?

Comment: yes @MaadhavSharma. It is on the same screen.

Comment: @its_broke_again. It is still the same. I tried to print the value of isEnabled it's working properly, when I on the switch it became true and when off it became false. The problem is the textformfield did not change to enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet is just working fine for me.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  bool status = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Switch Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomSwitch(
              activeColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
              value: status,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print("VALUE : $value");
                setState(() {
                  status = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            Text('Value : $status', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0
            ),),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            TextFormField(
          enabled: status,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Name', disabledBorder: InputBorder.none),
        )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh.. I see, maybe the problem is my CustomSwitch and the TextFormField is inside the AlertDialog. Thanks!

Comment: @CodeFloat True, Alert Dialogue is a stateless widget. To setstate in it u would need to use StatefulBuilder inside of alert dialogue. Do let me know if help regarding that is needed